How to specify `--ignore-environment` for `nix develop` by configuration?
Is there a way to always invoke the command-line option: --ignore-environment for the nix develop command, by configuration in some config file?
The value of this would be to ensure that a Nix Flake project will always invoke a pure Nix development shell on anyone's machine, since it would be in version control, avoiding the developer forgetting to invoke the command line option manually.

Currently, there isn't a way to configure the behavior of the nix develop command specifically. You may want to consider using the pure-eval option from nix.conf (last checked in Nix 2.24), but keep in mind but it will affect all of your Nix builds, not only the development shell. You can set this option from the flake.nix as
{
  inputs = ...
  outputs = ...
  nixConfig = { pure-eval = true; };
}

As an alternative, you can use tools like direnv to run nix develop --ignore-environment automatically when entering your project directory.
